# How to parse a String[] in tests with Spring Boot Reactive Webflux?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux

In my spring boot app, I want to write a web-test.

My application returns a list of strings. The test however produces a list with only one element (complete json as string).

My (minimal example) production code:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class BackendApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(BackendApplication.class, args);
    }

}

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/allBoxes")
class StackOverFlowController {

    @GetMapping
    public List<String> getNamesOfAllBoxes() {
        return List.of("Fruits", "Regional");
    }
}
```

My test class:

```
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
class StackOverFlowControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    WebTestClient webTestClient;

    @Test
    void whenListOfStringsEndpoint_thenExpectListOfStrings(){
        // When
        List<String> actual = webTestClient.get()
                .uri("/allBoxes")
                .exchange()
                .expectStatus().is2xxSuccessful()
                .expectBodyList(String.class)
                .returnResult()
                .getResponseBody();
        // Then

        Assertions.assertEquals(List.of("Fruits", "Regional"), actual);
    }
}
```

My maven dependencies (spring boot 2.7.0 parent):

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

The test fails:

```
org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: 
Expected :[Fruits, Regional]
Actual   :[["Fruits","Regional"]]
```

However, if I access the production application via postman, I receive:

```
["Fruits","Regional"]
```

Why does the reactive WebTestClient not parse this json, but instead create an array with only one string? How can I tell it to parse the string and give me a list of strings (with my two items as elements) instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you replace

```
.expectBodyList(String.class)
```

by

```
.expectBody(new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<String>>() {})
```

it works. Like this:

```
@Test
void whenListOfStringsEndpoint_thenExpectListOfStrings(){
    // When
    List<String> actual = webTestClient.get()
            .uri("/allBoxes")
            .exchange()
            .expectStatus().is2xxSuccessful()
            .expectBody(new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<String>>() {})
            .returnResult()
            .getResponseBody();
    // Then
    Assertions.assertEquals(List.of("Fruits", "Regional"), actual);
}
```

Comment: Kotlin: `.expectBody(object : ParameterizedTypeReference<List<String>>() {})`

Answer (score 0):

Check the default behaviour of `Jackson2Decoder` of `Spring WebClient`

https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/web-reactive.html#webflux-codecs-jackson

For a multi-value publisher, `WebClient` by default collects the values with `Flux#collectToList()` and then `serializes` the resulting collection.

You will need to `deserialize` accordingly.